# WooCommerce move shop page description after products loop

Tags: woocommerce

On the shop page of my WooCommerce website, I would like to move the page description after the products loop like this:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnhZW.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri7nG.png)

Is there a way to do this with a hooked function that can go in the function.php file of my child theme?

I found this function, but it only works for category pages, not for the main shop page

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'custom_archive_description', 2 );
function custom_archive_description(){
    if( is_product_category() ) :
        remove_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 5 );
    endif;
}
```